# Laravel throws Facade root error on key:generate in pipeline

Tags: laravel, gitlab-ci

I just tried to push a commit on a project. When this happens, my GitLab CI picks it up and tries to install the projects dependencies via Composer in it's Docker container. After installing the dependencies, it'll copy the `.env.example` file to `.env` and run `php artisan key:generate`

However, when it does this, my pipeline crashes on the following:

```
 $ php artisan key:generate
 In Facade.php line 258:

   A facade root has not been set.
```

I've tried to set the key locally in various ways, removed composer depenencies and reinstalled them, but in none of those scenarios, I encounter this error in my local environment.

Is this a known bug in Laravel? (6.18.0)

Thanks.